# Gorm updating user table when insert a record inside the table

Tags: go, go-gorm

When I try to insert a record into `battle` table, I don't know why but, the user records are updating in `users` table. How to fix it? Here is my code:

```
func CreateBattle(user1 User, user2 User) Battle {

battle := Battle{
    User1ID: user1.ID,
    User2ID: user2.ID,
    User1:   user1,
    User2:   user2,
}

GetDB().Create(&battle)


return battle
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate this _the user records are updating in users table_ ?

Comment: sure. i am using gorm for database query's. when i create a battle with the function that i shared then the user's row are updating(updated_at column)